# Tem como capturar eventos tipo quando apertar uma tecla em C++? [CodeBlocks]

Tags: c, c++

bom dia, estou fazendo um bot de autoclick para uso pessoal e gostaria de adicionar a funcao de pausar os clicks quando se apertar uma tecla especifica mas não sei se isso é possivel de se fazer no C++... bom, se alguem souber me ajudar agradeço. obs Source Code abaixo

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    //Declaracao das Variáveis a Serem Usadas <>
    int n = 1;
    int x;
    int y;
    int times;
    int done = 0;
    int sleepy;
    int botao;
    string choice;
    //Fim da Declaração de Variáveis </>

    //Declaração das funcoes a serem utilizadas <>
    void Clicar(int x, int y);
    void ClicarDireito(int x, int y);
    void ClicarMeio(int x, int y);
    void Digitar(char letra);
    //Fim da declaração de funções </>

    start:

//Inicio da coleta de dados <>
cout << "BOT_AutoClick Version 2.1" << endl;
cout << "   " << endl;

cout << "Quantas Vezes Deseja Clicar?" << endl;
cout << " : ";
cin >> times;

cout << "Quanto tempo deve ter entre os click? (Em Milisegundos)" << endl;
cout << "(MS): ";
cin >> sleepy;

cout << "Qual o botao a ser clicado : 1 - left / 2 - middle / 3 - right" <<     endl;
cout << " : ";
do{
cin >> botao;
}while( botao < 1 || botao > 3);

done = 0;
//Fim da Coleta de dados </>

//Contagem Regressiva para posicionar o mouse <>
cout << "starting in 5..." << endl;
Sleep(1000);
cout << "starting in 4..." << endl;
Sleep(1000);
cout << "starting in 3..." << endl;
Sleep(1000);
cout << "starting in 2..." << endl;
Sleep(1000);
cout << "starting in 1..." << endl;
Sleep(1000);
//Fim da Contagem Regressiva para posicionar o mouse </>

//Estrutura de Decisao para clicker C++ <>
if (botao == 1){

    while (done <= times)
    {
        Sleep(sleepy);
        Clicar(x, y); //Para Ver Função do click descer codigo
        done++;
    }
}

if (botao == 2){

        while (done <= times)
    {
        Sleep(sleepy);
        ClicarMeio(x, y); //Para Ver Função do click descer codigo
        done++;
    }
}

    if (botao == 3){

        while (done <= times){

        Sleep(sleepy);
        ClicarDireito(x, y); //Para Ver Função do click descer codigo
        done++;
        }
    }
    //Fim da Estrutura de Decisão do Clicker </>

    cout << "Processo Concluido com Sucesso!." << endl;
    cout << "BOT Autoclick - Criado por Mazurco066." << endl;
    cout << "    " << endl;
    Sleep(1000);
    cout << "Denovo?   sim(y) or nao(n)" << endl;
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == "y")
    {

        system("cls");
        goto start;
    }

    cin.get();

}

void Clicar(int x, int y){

    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
}

void ClicarDireito(int x, int y){

    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
}

void ClicarMeio(int x, int y){

    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP, x, y, 0, 0);
}

void Digitar(char letra){

    keybd_event(VkKeyScan(letra),0x9e,0,0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando apenas o windows você pode usar a função [GetAsyncKeyState()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx), que `determina se uma tecla está apertada ou desapertada no momento em que a função é executada`
Implementando no seu código ficaria assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;


//Declaração das funcoes a serem utilizadas <>
void Clicar(int x, int y);
void ClicarDireito(int x, int y);
void ClicarMeio(int x, int y);
void Digitar(char letra);
//Fim da declaração de funções </>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

//Declaracao das Variáveis a Serem Usadas <>
int n = 1;
int x;
int y;
int times;
int done = 0;
int sleepy;
int botao;
string choice;

unsigned long tempoEspera = 0;
unsigned long tempoEsperaClique = 0;
bool bPause = false;

//Fim da Declaração de Variáveis </>


start:

//Inicio da coleta de dados <>
cout << "BOT_AutoClick Version 2.1" << endl;
cout << "   " << endl;

cout << "Quantas Vezes Deseja Clicar?" << endl;
cout << " : ";
cin >> times;

cout << "Quanto tempo deve ter entre os click? (Em Milisegundos)" << endl;
cout << "(MS): ";
cin >> sleepy;

cout << "Qual o botao a ser clicado : 1 - left / 2 - middle / 3 - right" <<     endl;
cout << " : ";
do{
cin >> botao;
}while( botao < 1 || botao > 3);

done = 0;
//Fim da Coleta de dados </>

//Contagem Regressiva para posicionar o mouse <>
cout << "starting in 5..." << endl;
Sleep(1000);
cout << "starting in 4..." << endl;
Sleep(1000);
cout << "starting in 3..." << endl;
Sleep(1000);
cout << "starting in 2..." << endl;
Sleep(1000);
cout << "starting in 1..." << endl;
Sleep(1000);
//Fim da Contagem Regressiva para posicionar o mouse </>



//Estrutura de Decisao para clicker C++ <>
if (botao == 1){

    while (done <= times)
    {
        if(GetAsyncKeyState('v') & 0x8000)
        {
            if( tempoEspera < GetTickCount() )
            {
                tempoEspera = GetTickCount() + 350; //esperar 350 milisegundos
                bPause = !bPause; //troca de true pra false ou false pra true
            }
        }
        if(bPause == false && tempoEsperaClique < GetTickCount())
        {
            tempoEsperaClique = GetTickCount() + sleepy;
            Clicar(x, y); //Para Ver Função do click descer codigo
            done++;
        }
    }
}

if (botao == 2){

    while (done <= times)
    {
        if(GetAsyncKeyState('v') & 0x8000)
        {
            if( tempoEspera < GetTickCount() )
            {
                tempoEspera = GetTickCount() + 350; //esperar 350 milisegundos
                bPause = !bPause; //troca de true pra false ou false pra true
            }
        }
        if(bPause == false && tempoEsperaClique < GetTickCount())
        {
            tempoEsperaClique = GetTickCount() + sleepy;
            ClicarMeio(x, y); //Para Ver Função do click descer codigo
            done++;
        }
    }
}

    if (botao == 3){


        while (done <= times){

        if(GetAsyncKeyState('v') & 0x8000)
        {
            if( tempoEspera < GetTickCount() )
            {
                tempoEspera = GetTickCount() + 350; //esperar 350 milisegundos
                bPause = !bPause; //troca de true pra false ou false pra true
            }
        }
             if(bPause == false && tempoEsperaClique < GetTickCount())
            {
            tempoEsperaClique = GetTickCount() + sleepy;
            ClicarDireito(x, y); //Para Ver Função do click descer codigo
            done++;
            }
        }
    }
    //Fim da Estrutura de Decisão do Clicker </>

    cout << "Processo Concluido com Sucesso!." << endl;
    cout << "BOT Autoclick - Criado por Mazurco066." << endl;
    cout << "    " << endl;
    Sleep(1000);
    cout << "Denovo?   sim(y) or nao(n)" << endl;
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == "y")
    {

        system("cls");
        goto start;
    }

    cin.get();

}

void Clicar(int x, int y){

    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
}

void ClicarDireito(int x, int y){

    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
}

void ClicarMeio(int x, int y){

    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP, x, y, 0, 0);
}

void Digitar(char letra){

    keybd_event(VkKeyScan(letra),0x9e,0,0);
}
```

Notas:

Declaração de funções devem ser feitas fora do escopo `main()`.

`Sleep()` é altamente não recomendável pois 'trava' ou 'pausa' toda a execução do programa e não é garantido 'dormir' exatamente o tempo passado. Se você criar um programa com mais threads iria pausar a execução das outras threads também.

Usando `GetTickCount()` você pode dar intervalos em milissegundos sem pausar a execução do programa.

Também é necessário usar `GetTickCount()` ao pressionar uma tecla para pausar ou não os cliques porquê se não for utilizado um delay entre o pressionamento das teclas, pela velocidade de execução do programa `bPause = !bPause` seria executado várias vezes em uma rápida pressionada de tecla.

Comment: vlw cara resolveu. eu estava usando um outro metodo de captura de tecla enquanto esperava mas estava ruim o metodo de pausa. obrigado msm